# Отображение изображения в JSP

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Здравствуйте, у меня в админке интернет магазина есть добавление изображения товара, изображения сохраняються в каталоге проекта ("/static/productPic/изорбражение.png").
Когда вывожу это изображение оно не отображаеться на странице.
Аннотация присутствует:`<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**"  location="/static/" />` 
Код из вьюшки:`<img src="<c:url value="/static/productPic/${product.orgNamePic}"/>" alt="альтернативный текст">`
В браузере отображаеться "альтернативный текст", такой путь изображения отображаеться в браузере: `/sombraShop/static/productPic/b9ebb62354b87f5753ca501f90dfa45c.jpg`

Comment: Проблема решена, забрал первый "/" и все заработало

Comment: Пожалуйста, опубликуйте свое решение как ответ и позже сможете его принять.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Проблема решена, забрал первый "/" и все заработало

Answer (score 0):

> изображения сохраняються в каталоге проекта ("/static/productPic/изорбражение.png")

Не очень понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду под "каталогом проекта" в данном случае. Насколько я понимаю, Spring и спецификация сервелатов тоже не в курсе что это и где искать.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**"  location="/static/" />
```

Насколько помню, `location` по умолчанию ищет в classpath-е. Ваш "каталог проекта" есть в classpath?

Очень рекомендую ознакомиться со следующей статьей о том как работает раздача статического контента в Spring MVC: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources

Comment: вот здесь лежит файл
ссылка на скриншот - https://pp.vk.me/c631526/v631526958/37c47/f0L1CJPvNWU.jpg

Comment: `location`, по умолчанию, ищет в корне war файла.